# I tried to use history.push. I got aw snap error by chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two popups in one page. I need to invoke one popup based on a condition, so I used `history.pushstate` but some time it's not working.

```
var stateObj = { page: 1 }; 
if($("#all-verified").val() == 'true'){ 
    history.pushState(stateObj, "title 1", "#mobileVerified"); 
}   
else{ 
    history.pushState(stateObj, "title 1", "#mobileNotVerified"); 
}
```